# mockito refuses to pair TypeSafeMatcher to a generic method API

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, mocking, mockito

I want to test my code that call some API:

```
public <T extends MessageLite> ApiFuture<String> publish(final T message) throws Exception {
}


public <T extends MessageLite> ApiFuture<String> publish(final T message, final ApiFutureCallback<T> futureCallback) throws Exception {
}


public <T> String publishSynchronous(final String message, final ApiFutureCallback<T> futureCallback) throws Exception {
}
```

in my test i use mockito mock and then i want to verify it was called with a proto object (extends MessageLite) that has a field `isSuccess = false`

I have tired this code:

```
    verify(customPublisher, times(0)).publish(isFailureResult(), anyObject());
```

and this matcher:

```
public class FailResultMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<MessageLite> {

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(final MessageLite sentResult) {
        return !((SdkResult)sentResult).getIsSuccess();
    }


    public static FailResultMatcher isFailureResult() {
        return new FailResultMatcher();
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(final Description description) {

    }
}
```

but i get an error in test compilation:

```
Error:(131, 42) java: no suitable method found for publish(com.w.sdkService.matchers.FailResultMatcher,java.lang.Object)
    method linqmap.cloud.google.pubsub.CustomPublisher.<T>publish(java.lang.String,com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; com.w.sdkService.matchers.FailResultMatcher cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
    method linqmap.cloud.google.pubsub.CustomPublisher.<T>publish(T) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method linqmap.cloud.google.pubsub.CustomPublisher.<T>publish(T,com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback<T>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: com.w.sdkService.matchers.FailResultMatcher
        upper bound(s): com.google.protobuf.MessageLite)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Dont explain so much how your code comes together. Pull it together and provide a [mcve]!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the documentation ([Mockito 1](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html) and [Mockito 2](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html)), you have to use `argThat(matcher)`, a Mockito matcher which allows you to use your custom argument matchers:

```java
 //stubbing
 when(mock.giveMe(argThat(new MyHamcrestMatcher())));

 //verification
 verify(mock).giveMe(argThat(new MyHamcrestMatcher()));
```

You did not say if you're using Mockito 1 or 2, but the idea is similar, it's just the static import that is different:

- 1: `import static org.mockito.Matchers.argThat;` (or for simplicity `org.mockito.Mockito` which extends `Matchers`)
- 2: `import static org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest.argThat;`

Bonus hint, for readability you can replace `times(0)` with [`never()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4), so in your case it would be:

```java
verify(customPublisher, never()).publish(argThat(isFailureResult()), anyObject());
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer is useful also when moving from Mockito 1 to Mockito 2 and helped me.

Also, with Mockito 2, if the parameter passed to `argThat` is a Mockito object you can use:
`import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.argThat`.